# How do I fit several linear models with plyr

Tags: r, plyr

How do I modify the following code from the help page of dlplyr to consecutively fit a linear model with no intercept to several predictors in a data.frame.

```
#From the dlplyr help page
linmod <- function(df) {
lm(rbi ~ year, data = mutate(df, year = year - min(year)))
}
models <- dlply(baseball, .(id), linmod)
```

My dataset

```
library(plyr)
grouping<-factor(sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 10, replace=TRUE))
set.seed(10)
x1<-rnorm(10, 3, 1)
x2<-rnorm(10, 4, 1)
x3<-rnorm(10,5, 1)
x4<-rnorm(10,5,2)
mydf<-data.frame(grouping, x1, x2, x3, x4)
mydf
```

I would like to modify the function linmod above to produce lm(y1~0+X1, data=mydf), lm(y1~0+X2, data=mydf), lm(y1~0+X3, data=mydf).
I want the linear models without an intercept to basically do an analysis of variance; this is how I usually do it.

Comment: Sorry the linear models should be lm(X1 ~ 0+grouping), lm(X2~0+grouping), lm(X3~0+grouping).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the following your desired output?

```
lapply(mydf[-1], function(x) lm(x ~ 0 + mydf[,1]))
$x1

Call:
lm(formula = x ~ 0 + mydf[, 1])

Coefficients:
mydf[, 1]A  mydf[, 1]B  mydf[, 1]C  
     2.511       2.608       2.405  


$x2

Call:
lm(formula = x ~ 0 + mydf[, 1])

Coefficients:
mydf[, 1]A  mydf[, 1]B  mydf[, 1]C  
     4.301       4.872       4.073  


$x3

Call:
lm(formula = x ~ 0 + mydf[, 1])

Coefficients:
mydf[, 1]A  mydf[, 1]B  mydf[, 1]C  
     4.410       2.848       4.358  


$x4

Call:
lm(formula = x ~ 0 + mydf[, 1])

Coefficients:
mydf[, 1]A  mydf[, 1]B  mydf[, 1]C  
     3.473       5.107       3.508
```

Comment: Thanks RStudent.  I should have thought of that myself.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easiest to gather the Xs then then have it as the variable that plyr splits before passing to lm. `Tidyr` is helpful for this. Something like:

```
library(plyr)
library(tidyr)
grouping<-factor(sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 10, replace=TRUE))
set.seed(10)
x1<-rnorm(10, 3, 1)
x2<-rnorm(10, 4, 1)
x3<-rnorm(10,5, 1)
x4<-rnorm(10,5,2)
mydf<-data.frame(grouping, x1, x2, x3, x4)
mydf_long <- gather(my_df, "x_var", "value", 2:5)
lm_fn <- function(x){
   out <- lm(value ~ grouping, data=x)
   return(out)
}
output <- dlply(bydf_long, .(x_var), lm_fn)
```